# Looping through children missing some divs - why?

Tags: jquery, each, children

I'm trying to get the total height of the children divs in a parent div "myDiv". Here's the structure:

```
<div style="height: 102px; display: block;" id="myDiv">
<div style="position: relative;" id="sf_0" class="reqCont ui-draggable" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    <div class="reqMsgCont">
        <div class="reqMsg"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="btnCont">
        <div class="expFold" id="i_0"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="e_0" class="exCont">
        <div id="d_0" class="exDel"></div>
        <div id="m_0" class="exMN"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="p_0" class="expSngs"></div>
</div>
```

I'm using:

```
var totalHeight =0;
$("#myDiv").children().each(function(){

        //totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
    alert(this.id);

});
```

The total was coming out funny, so I set an alert to show the ids, and the only ids that are shown are sf_0 and p_0. Why is it missing the rest?

I though it may be because I'm creating the divs dynamically, but I create them at the same time, and then:

```
$("#myDiv").append(rO);
```

And then run the above each loop after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children will only give you the divs 1 level deep/

Instead change it to :

```
var totalHeight =0;
$("#myDiv").find("div").each(function(){

        //totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight(true);
    alert(this.id);

});
```

Comment: I thought it was working, but it's still not picking up heights. I have a div in the main div that is set in css for height:100px, but alerting it shows it as 0px. I don't think it's your code though - hard coding in alert("HEIGHT: "+$("#i_0").height()); after $("#myDiv").append(rO); shows it as 0, though it's 100px on the screen.

Comment: If you have the height specified using css, you can access it using parseInt($(this).css("height"))

Comment: I will try that now Matt - thanks. I hard coded a test - alert("height: "+$("#testme").outerHeight(true)); shows 20 for <div id="testme">blah blah</div>, but 0 for <div id="testme"><a href="#">fghgfh</a></div> - any idea why the text in the link doesn't count towards the height?

Answer (score 2):

`children()` will give you only direct children nodes,if you want to have them all checked, I suggest use `find()` method